# Python os- When I create a directory using os.mkdir, os.path.isdir tells me the directory does not exist

Tags: python, operating-system

I am writing a fairly simple journal entry program, and I need to check if a directory exists and if it doesn't, I need to create one.

In journal.py I am importing another module: files. This module handles the creation and deletion of files and directories

**journal.py**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if files.testForDir('entries') == False:
        print 'Directory "entries" does not exist'
        print 'Attempting to create directory'
        files.createDir('entires')
```

**files.py**

```
def testForDir(dirname, path=os.getcwd()):
    pathtotest = os.path.join(path, dirname)
    return os.path.isdir(pathtotest)

def createDir(dirname, path=os.getcwd()):
    dirpath = os.path.join(path, dirname)
    try:
        os.mkdir(dirpath)
    except OSError as error:
        print error
```

**My problem:** When I create the directory inside Ubuntu, *testForDir()* returns the correct result. It also runs correctly when I run the program without /entries. It creates the directory using *os.mkdir()* and /entries shows up in Ubuntu. However, when I run it after the directory was created by *os.mkdir()*, *testForDir()* returns False and an OSError exception is raised as the folder already exists.

So to present the problem formally, and repeat myself: When I create a directory using *os.mkdir()*, *os.path.isdir()* tells me the directory does not exist.

**System Information:** Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32bit, Python 2.7.

File structure: home/name/Programs/journal/.

Journal contains: entries.py(blank), files.py, journal.py, entries(dir)

Comment: Aside: `path=os.getcwd()` may not do what you think it does.  It doesn't get the current directory each time the function is called: it gets the current directory *once*, when the function is defined.  If you later change the cwd, the functions will still use the original path.

Comment: @DSM Thanks, I may actually need to change the working directory later!

Comment: The usual idiom is to use some variation on `def f(path=None): path = path if path is not None else os.getcwd()` to avoid this problem.

Comment: I don't recognize the syntax in the code example you provided. path = path? Edit: I know what your getting at though!

Comment: It's one line, equivalent to `if path is None: path = os.getcwd()`.  Google `python ternary`.  You can write `path = something if condition else some_other_value`.  In this case, `something` simply happens to be `path`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a spelling mistake:

```
'entries' != 'entires'
```

stop hardcoding the same string in multiple places (mis-spelling is one risk, but it's also unnecessarily painful to change later).

Put it in a variable, and Python will be able to warn you if you mis-spell the variable name.

Comment: Wow. Just wow. I can't believe I missed that. Thanks.

Comment: @Koldof -- If this answer fixed your problem, feel free to accept it (click the little checkmark next to the answer).  That way others know that your issue has been solved.  You'll also get a small reputation boost too ...

Answer (score 0):

I think the whole thing can be simpler:

```
try:
    somfunc(dirpath)
except:
    os.mkdir(dirpath)
    somfunc(dirpath)
```